# modal Pop Up window not waiting for Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i have tried all my possible best and searched every where but to no avail that is why i have decided to do this after about 4years of learning from this website.

i noticed that my modal pop up window is not waiting for my ajax that sends the value retrived from the anchor tag which is then sent to the PHP file here by casuing the php to give an index undefined error. but if i just use the alert() on success: function() i see the values been retrived from the anchor tag. now this is my code the html link `<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="editr" data-id="<?php echo $postID; ?>" data-owner="<?php echo $op; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form" >Edit Page</a>`

```
$(function(){
    $("#editr").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var owner =  $(this).attr("data-owner");
        var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&user=' + owner;
        $.ajax({
            url: "../config/edit.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this is the modal part

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Form in moadl</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            
             <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Email address</label>
     
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                  </div>
        
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </form>
            
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is the php code <?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$owner = $_POST['user'];
if(isset($id))
{
 echo"value passed successfully"; 
}
else
{
 
 echo "value not passed";
}
?>

Comment: you need to call it after $.ajax({

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: have you tried writing your modal opening code inside your `sucess:` function? also `$(this).attr("data-id")` is equivalent to `$(this).data("id")`

Comment: no i haven't , i just saw the modal code somewhere and i copied it. i wasn't the one who wrote it

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the promise to return and then continue on with what you were trying to do.

```
$(function(){
$("#editr").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var owner =  $(this).attr("data-owner");
    var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&user=' + owner;
    var promise = $.ajax({
        url: "../config/edit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : dataString,
        cache: false
    });
    promise.then(function(data){
        //show modal with data (in place of alert)
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: don't you think this is another way of writing the `success` or `complete` function of `ajax()`?

Comment: What appears to be happening is the server side method is not returning the data instantly and the modal will not update itself after the fact so you need to "await" the returning data before continuing.

Comment: how will i do that please